# Is it possible to assign a keyboard shortcut for toggling a preference?

Tags: customization, shortcut

I would like to be able to toggle ToolTips on and off, however being that it's a value in Blender's Preferences I don't see anything register in the Console when I enable or disable it. This makes me think it may not be possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to it. Does anyone know if there's a way? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As sambler points out, my answer is overkill for your purposes. However the general question deserves an answer too: *How to assign a toggle shortcut to a preference*.

Make a new keyboard shortcut or re-appropriate a shortcut you don't use.

*UserPreferences -> Input -> Window*

[image]

If you add a `wm.context_toggle` and hit enter you'll get another field called "Context Attributes". It might appear that you can't type into that field but you can. Paste into it:

```
user_preferences.view.show_tooltips
# or
user_preferences.view.show_tooltips_python
```

depending on what you need.

Comment: Thank you both for the very helpful answers! @zeffi I'm marking yours as the accepted answer because it is most relevant to the question title and therefor most likely to be helpful to others viewing. Also, I may use the method to toggle some other preference in the future. As for quickly viewing a ToolTip, I will use sambler's shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

For the specific case you mention you don't need to add a shortcut as a temporary show tooltips feature already exists.

In the preferences disable tooltips. When you want to see a tooltip hold down <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> and move your mouse over the item and you will see the tooltip.